# mingw64 system("command") not same as "command" in shell

Tags: c, windows, bash, mingw-w64, msys

A program "execinput" reads input lines from stdin
and stores them into a character array "buffer" and then does this:

```c
system(buffer);
```

Let "command" be any valid set of programs, parameters, and bash syntax.  Ideally the next two lines would give the same result (neglecting for the moment the handling of any double quotes within "command"):

```
command
echo "command" | execinput
```

That is indeed the case on a linux system running in a bash shell.  However, in bash in an "Msys2 MingW 32bit" shell this happens (trailing semicolon after the 3 is intentional):

```
echo 1; echo 2; echo 3;
1
2
3
echo "echo 1; echo 2; echo 3;" | execinput
1 ; echo 2; echo 3;
echo "echo 1 & echo 2 & echo 3;" | execinput
1
2
3;
```

The "&" character is what cmd.exe uses to separate sub-commands.  That last command on a linux system, either directly in bash or through system() gives:

```
3
1
2
```

In the linux bash environment all the commands come out the same, whether run directly or via `system()` in `execinput()`. In the MSYS2 environment they don't.

I believe that `COMSPEC` and `PATH` are involved somehow but having set the former like so:

```
 export COMSPEC="C:\progs\msys32\usr\bin\bash.exe -c "
```

instead of the default COMSPEC value of:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

the results still were not the same.

Can somebody please explain what is going on here, and hopefully, how to make "command" come out the same directly on a bash command line and when invoked with `system()`?

---

More info.  In a bash command line in MSYS2:

```
echo 'set' | execinput > short.txt
echo 'bash -c "set"' | execinput > long.txt
```

then compare the file contents.  key differences are:

> 1. long.txt has 11 BASH *symbols plus DIRSTACK, EUID, GROUPS, 
>      IFS, MACHTYPE, OPTERR, OPTIND, OSTYPE, PPID, SHELLOPTS,UID.
>      Short.txt does not have these.
> 2. SYSTEMROOT, COMSPEC, CONTITLE, HOMEPATH, and many others are 
>      in single quotes in long.txt, no quotes in short.txt.
>      The strings are otherwise the same.
> 3. PWD is in fully linux/posix syntax in long.txt and has its root
>      at the top of the MSYS2 file system.  PWD is in hybrid syntax 
>      in short.txt (starts with C: then has a / delimited path) and is
>      the full Windows path.
> 4. PATH in long.txt starts with linux/posix syntax entries,
>      root at the top of the MSYS2 file system, then followed by entries
>      like /c/Windows/System32.  Short.txt has entries which are in full
>      Windows syntax.
> 5. Long.txt has SHLVL=2, short.txt has SHLVL=1.

Comment: This is on a Windows 7 system, AFAIK WSL does not work there.   Obviously if linux was an option I wouldn't be trying to make this work in MSYS2 on W7!

Comment: Upgrade to Windows 10 ^^

Comment: `cygwin` is much more reliable/complete than `mingw` if you can't use WSL.

Comment: @o11c well they are different things; mingw-w64 is a compiler , whereas cygwin is a POSIX implementation. If you don't want a posix implementation then cygwin is a waste of time, as well as delaying your access to the latest versions of the compiler since you have to wait for the cygwin maintainers to make new packages.

Comment: @M.M cygwin and mingw both include a compiler *and* a runtime. This question boils down to "why isn't this runtime sane?"

Comment: @o11c Not sure what you mean by "runtime" in this context; mingw-w64 can build executables that target native Windows with no runtime dependencies other than already-present OS components

Comment: Even in unix, system() doesn't invoke bash, but sh, by default, which can have subtle differences.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you assume that `command` stands for "Bash syntax".

However, the `system()` call is calling `sh` on your Gnu/Linux and `cmd.exe` on your Windows system. Being interpreted by different shells leads to different results of the two command lines passed into the `system()` call:

```
echo 1; echo 2; echo 3;
echo 1 & echo 2 & echo 3;
```

I don't know if there is any way to make `system()` call a different command processor on Windows, if `COMPSPEC` does not seem to affect it.

If you have control over the source code of `execinput`, I would suggest implementing a more portable execution of `command` there, e.g. using one of the `exec*()` system calls together with a defined path to the desired shell.

Comment: Not so sure what is being called in MSYS2.  When run from bash `echo "pwd" | execinput` gives the working directory.  However, run in cmd.exe `echo "pwd" | (PATH)\execinput.exe` and it gives the same error that running pwd directly in cmd.exe would.  So system() seems to depend in some way on which environment it is run from.   In both cases COMSPEC lists `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`.

Comment: Using the `extract` program to get better control of quotes: `echo 1; extract -fmt 'bash -c "echo 1; echo 2; echo 3;"' | execinput` gives the expected result.   Perhaps without the extra quoting `cmd.exe` sees the command first and breaks it into subcommands before bash can.  The syntax here makes multiple commands look like one to cmd.exe, so bash receives the desired payload.  Still not sure why system() cannot call bash.exe directly, seems like COMSPEC should do that.

Comment: I don't know about `extract` use for quoting (wasn't that the program used to extract cabinet files?). Have you considered modifying `execinput`? Does your solution have to be portable or will it run on that one target platform only? Will it be called in different ways or do you have control over how it is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

"Msys2 MingW 32bit" means that you open a MSYS2 Bash shell where the path is set so that `gcc` resolves to a mingw-w64 build targeting native Win32. The native Win32 executable has nothing to do with MSYS2 Bash; the command processor is `cmd.exe`.  The MSYS2 shell is only a development tool.

If you open "Msys2 MSYS2" then `gcc` resolves to a mingw-w64 build targeting the MSYS2 system. You can check the target with `gcc -v` and it will say `Target: x86_64-pc-msys` or similar.  I tested this and it did use `/usr/bin/bash` as the command processor as expected.

Note that the different targets use different gcc installations; the MSYS2 target is `pacman -S msys2/gcc` and the native Win32 target is `pacman -S mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gcc`.   It does not use a single compiler which selects target via a switch, like some gcc builds.

Of course, if you build targeting MSYS2 then the resulting executable must be run under MSYS2.

Comment: The executable does not need to be run under MSYS2!  If one copies all the required dll's into the executable's directory binaries made in MSYS2 will also run under cmd.exe, incuding on other Windows systems with no MSYS2 present.  Use ntldd to identify those libraries.  For comand line programs that read from and write to files that is sufficient. Graphics programs are more involved as fonts and such must also be copied and placed where the program can find them.

Comment: @mathog I would describe that as running under msys2 (msys2 is just a collection of files after all)